# Python json.dumps equivalent that returns a dictionary with built-in data types

Tags: python, json

I'm working with a library that contains a number of classes that are subclasses of the `dict` type. I can get a JSON string of the object by calling the following:

```
import json

json.dumps(customer, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
```

However, I'm working with a NoSQL database and I need to convert this class to a dictionary in order to properly save it. Unfortunately, calling `dict(customer)` does not provide me with a valid structure since a number of it's objects are unhashable types. However, I discovered I can perform a `json.dumps` and `json.loads` to convert the object to a dictionary that I can now save:

```
import json

json_str = json.dumps(customer, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
customer_obj = json.loads(json_str)

# I can now save the customer_obj
```

Ultimately, I would like to know if there is more direct way to create my JSON-like dictionary without subsequently calling `json.dumps` and `json.loads`.

Comment: What NoSQL database are you using and what python db client/driver? Thanks.

Comment: I'm using DynamoDB with Boto3. Also, if it helps, I'm attempting to save Customer objects from Stripe's Python API (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/blob/master/stripe/resource.py).